# difference between 持ち込む and 持って来る？

Tags: verbs

Looking at examples on weblio, it looks like maybe 持ち込む is more for things and 持ってくる is for bringing people along with you, etc?

Comment: Note the different in your title and your body もちくる　vs. もってくる. Those are grammatically different.

Comment: Ah right ><
So is もちくる a thing then?

Comment: もちくる does exist, but the two expressions in the title (and the newly edited version of the question body) are much more common.

Comment: @virmaior What's もちくる?

Comment: @snailboat it has a definition here: http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E6%8C%81%E3%81%A1%E6%9D%A5%E3%82%8B though no examples... So presumably it exists somewhere. The definition makes sense to me if we view it is as "I will go get ~ and come back" (持ち as 連体形 + くる). But I've never seen it anywhere so I assumed OP was making an error in transcription

Comment: @virmaior Although I notice the page you linked to says もちきたる and not もちくる・・・

Answer (score 4, accepted):

持ち込む is to bring things inside, take something into.

持ってくる is just to bring things.

None of them are used for people. That would be 連れてくる.

Comment: 連れ込む・・・←　ちょっと危ない・・

Comment: I assume @Choko is referring to this defn of 連れ込む: 愛人を連れて旅館などにはいり込む。